# Galois representation, Tate twist

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

It is said (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tate+twist):

> To return to our starting point, a crucial remark here is that whilst $\mathbb{Z}_{l}(1)$ is non-canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{l}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_{l}$-module, the two are not isomorphic as Galois representations. Thus the presence of Tate twists is indispensable to the arithmetic aspect of cohomology.

What is the Galois representation of a sheaf? What is the arithmetic aspect of (étale) cohomology?

Comment: I think here by 'Galois representation' they just mean the trivial l-adic representation and the 1-dimensional representation corresponding to some cyclotomic character. They view the Tate twist as an $\mathbb{Z}_{l}$-module which admits an action of Galois group.

Comment: Many voluminous books have been written to answer the question "what is the arithmetic aspect of etale cohomology", but the key idea is that if $X$ is a variety over a field $K$, and $\bar{X}$ its extension to the separable closure of $K$, then the etale cohomology of $\bar{X}$ (with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$, or generally in any sheaf coming from $X$) is naturally a representation of the Galois group of $K$, and this construction is of fundamental importance in constructing and studying Galois representations.

Comment: @Erica Can you elaborate on that more and maybe make it into an answer? Thank you!

Comment: @SayakoHoshimiya What I said can be found in the beginning of Chapter 2, CMI Notes on p-adic Hodge theory by Brinon and Conrad.